# Can't get Inkscape image into TeXstudio

Tags: pdf, inkscape

I can't get my inkscape drawing as a pdf into TeXstudio. The name on the Inkscape file is drawing. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,import}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
        \input{drawing.pdf}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

After I run this, I get myriad error messages, and I have no idea what they mean. They say something like 'invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.' What's going on here?

Comment: `\includegraphics{drawin.pdf}` or `\includepdf{drawing.pdf}` after loading `\usepackage{pdfpages}` for the second .... `\input` command inserts LaTeX source code... Search for these commands to find out that they can accept `[width=\columnwidth]` as optional argument or `\textwidth` etc

Comment: Thank you. Finally got it to work.

Comment: Nice ... Happy TeXing